# Updating Django App on server

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn

I am relatively new to Python/Django and have successfully deployed my first app. I want to update it now with some new changes, but I am not sure what the proper process is. My setup is ubuntu/nginx/gunicorn/postgres.

At the moment I am taking the following steps:

1. Stop nginx: sudo service nginx stop
2. Stop gunicorn: sudo service gunicorn stop
3. Backup the db? (not implemented - cant find it on the server)
4. Git Pull
5. python manage.py migrate
6. python manage.py collectstatic
7. restart gunicorn:  sudo service gunicorn start
8. restart nginx: sudo service nginx restart

This is working, but I would appreciate some guidance if this is the complete, most accurate and safest way to do this please?

Comment: Backups aren't something you do when you update, they're something you do on a regular (daily/weekly) basis. And there's no need to stop nginx.

Comment: Do you want to automate your updates? I can recommend *Fabric*. But *why* do you have to stop **nginx** when updating **django**?

Comment: I simply stopped nginx as I thought that was necessary to stop serving requests, but I will remove that step now - thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One lazy (yet recommended **and** professional) way of going about app updates is running automation script, like [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) or [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/).

However, if you wish to proceed the manual way (which is tedious), you might do something like:

- Pull from git
- Run migrations `python manage.py migrate` (This should ensure changes you made locally to your models reflect in production DB)
- Run static collections to ensure new statics are reflected in server /static/ folder like so: `python manage.py collectstatic`
- Then, restart your **Django Server** not Nginx. So something like: `sudo service your_django_server_running_instance restart`

On digitalOcean for instance (when used One-Click Install), your django server running instance is likely called *gunicorn*

Then you might want to look into [automating your postgresql db](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux) as well

Comment: I haven't learned anywhere yet that running makemigrations on server **isn't good practice**. Assuming it is bad practice, then, ask, 'How are you going to get your model changes to DB?' Because there's no magic way of updating DB, without hitting the DB

Comment: @RunLoop is correct. You should run makemigrations locally in dev, commit to source control, push to the server, and run migrate there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Okay. I didn't know that, but any explanation why that's the best approach? I'm curious

Comment: Because migrations are part of your source code and need to be in the repo. You shouldn't be generating them on the server. The main point of migrations is to ensure that your dev and prod databases are the same; generating them separately defeats that.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Makes sense. Thanks

Comment: WARNING - Never push local migrations to the server - these should be in your git ignore. Each db should create and run its own migrations -  I learned this the hard way unfortunately.